# Swift Firebase Logged in user does not update after logout and login go new user

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, swiftui

EDIT: I've managed to provide a solution to the problem myself.

I have declared 
`func update() { … }` 
under my init() function of my UserData class, which basically executes the same code as my init() function, and I call self.userData.update() when a user logs in, registers or logs out, so the EnvironmentObject always stays up to date.

When I log out of my current account and log in to a new user, the EnvironmentObject called UserData, which collects all the user's data from Firestore, won't update and the old user will display instead of the new one. I don't know how to fix this issue. This problem also occurs when I register a new user. My other EnvironmentObjects of this user also don't update.

RegisterView:

```
 // Registrier Button
                Button(action: {
                    if(self.password == self.passwordConfirmation) {
                        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.password) { (authResult, error) in
                            // Prüfen, ob Nutzer erfolgreich erstellt wurde
                            guard let user = authResult?.user, error == nil else {
                                // Fehlermeldung anzeigen
                                self.errorMessage = Text(error!.localizedDescription)
                                self.showAlert = true
                                self.alertTitle = Text("Fehler")
                                return
                            }

                            // Nutzer erfolgreich registriert
                            self.errorMessage = Text("\(user.email!) erfolgreich erstellt!")
                            self.showAlert = true
                            self.alertTitle = Text("Erfolg")

                            let db = Firestore.firestore()
                            db.collection("users").document(String(user.uid)).setData([
                                "E-Mail": self.email, "Name": self.name, "account": "user","uid": user.uid,"reserviert": "none", "customerID": "NULL"])


                            // Change View
                            self.registerSuccess = true
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        self.errorMessage = Text("Deine Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!")
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    RegisterButtonContent()
                }
```

LogInView:

```
            // Login Button
        Button(
        action: {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.email, password: self.password) { (authResult, error) in
                guard let user = authResult?.user, error == nil else {
                    self.errorMessage = Text(error!.localizedDescription)
                    self.showAlert = true
                    return
                }

                self.isLoggedIn = true
            }
        }) {
            LoginButtonContent()
        }.padding()
```

UserData, which does not get updated:

```
class UserData: ObservableObject {
```

//    static let shared = UserData()

```
@Published var user = User(id: "", name: "", email: "", account: "", reserviert: "", customerID: "")    // 0: Name; 1: E-Mail; 2: User ID; 3: User(Bool))

init ()  {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        print("No user")
        return
    }
    let userData = db.collection("users").document(String(userID))

    userData.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { (snap, err) in
        guard let document = snap else {
            print("Document does not exist")
            return
        }

        guard let data = document.data() else {
            print("Document was empty")
            return
        }

        self.user = User(id: data["uid"] as! String, name: data["Name"] as! String, email: data["E-Mail"] as! String, account: data["account"] as! String, reserviert: data["reserviert"] as! String, customerID: data["customerID"] as! String)
    }
}
```

}

SceneDelegate:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var data = UserData()
var lounges = getLoungeData()
var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
var reservierungsInfos = getReservierungsInfos()


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(viewRouter).environmentObject(data).environmentObject(lounges).environmentObject(reservierungsInfos))
        } else {
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(viewRouter))
        }
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here, but there can **only** be one user signed in at a time.  If you allow a new user to sign in, then the old one will be signed out immediately.  This behavior can't be changed.

Comment: Yes, but when the new user is signed in I want my environment objects to be updated to conform to the new user and hold the data of that user, but it does not do that and I don't know how to change that

Comment: What did you do to update them in the first place?  It sounds like you will have to do that again.

Comment: Well the environment objects have got snapshot listeners, but they only listen to changes of the document of the previous user. Now I want to change the snapshot listener to listen to changes of the new user, or just load the new user in the first place.
When I restart the app the new user is loaded, but I want the new user to load as soon as I log him in or register him.

Comment: OK, sounds like you'll have to set up all those listeners all over again after the new user signs in.

Comment: Yes, but how do I update the snapshot listener?? Because right now they just stay the same and I don't quite now how to set them up again after the user changes.

Comment: You don't update it.  You remove it completely and add a new one.